# Creating Picture control dynamically in CView SDI Application

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to add an image control to the `CView` at runtime. Can anybody share some sample source code and format of the image that I am going to use is bitmap.

Comment: Take look at this post [Animating a CImage to fade in on creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073998/animating-a-cimage-to-fade-in-on-creation)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to implement `OnPaint` of your `CView`-derived class:

```
void CImageView::OnPaint()
{
  CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
  CRect rc;
  GetClientRect(&rc);
  CImage image;
  image.LoadFromResource(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), IDB_BITMAP1);
  image.Draw(dc.m_hDC, rc.left, rc.top, rc.Width(), rc.Height(), 0, 0,
              image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight());
}
```

In this example the image is loaded from BITMAP resource.

To load image from file use `CImage::Load()` method. It does support the following formats: BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG and TIFF.